# Как сделать свой ключ для шифровки DES?

Tags: c#, шифрование

Как сделать свой ключ для шифровки DES на C#?

Comment: Что значит свой ключ? Вам нужно снегенерировать ключ что бы что-то зашифровать?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы инициализировать свой собственный шифратор DES, воспользуйтесь методом `CreateEncryptor(Byte[] key, Byte[] IV)` объекта класса `DESCryptoServiceProvider`. 
На вход нужно подать байт-массив ключа и байт-массив вектора инициализации. Также нужно позаботиться о длине ключа, т.к. DES работает с длиной ключа, равной половине блока данных, на которые вы разбили исходный текст для шифрования.

Ключ можете сгенерировать из строки:

```
 System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
 Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(stringKey);
```

[Ссылка на MSDN по теме](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0dh224hh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример вставки ключа в DES!